# Git branch status output

Tags: git

Can someone explain this git output:

Pulling a branch from master to run on a local node:

```
> git pull origin xyz

> git status
# On branch xyz 
#Your branch is ahead of 'origin/xyz' by 22 commits.
#Changed but not updated: 
  ... lots of modified stuff
```

ok, we want to purge the local changes...

```
> git log | head
#commit a49b36fd6635f7dd6f72bd256231b3179920ffa4 ...

> git reset --hard a49b36fd6635f7dd6f72bd256231b3179920ffa4
# On branch xyz
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/xyz' by 22 commits. (huh?)

nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

So, if it's clean and there's nothing to commit, what can be meant by "branch ahead of origin"? running "git diff" returns no output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git diff` with no arguments diffs your workspace against the index.

If you want to diff against a branch, tell it so:

```
git diff origin/xyz
```

When git says you're 'ahead' it means that you have unpushed changes relative to the upstream remote branch. In this case it seems your upstream is 'origin/xyz'. If you push then run status again, this message will go away.

Similarly if you `git fetch` then `git status`, if changes were fetched you will see a message stating you are *behind* by a number of commits. If you have unpushed changes and the remote changed since you started your edits (ie. you've diverged) then you'll see you are both ahead and behind!

By the way if you want to purge local changes, you can do so using `git clean` instead of `reset --hard`. Alternatively you can simplify your two lines into `git reset --hard HEAD`.

---

**EDIT** if you have changes locally that you wish to throw away then you can use `reset` to move your workspace to the remote ref.

```
git reset --hard origin/xyz
```

This will move the current branch to the same commit as `origin/xyz`. Note that any changed files will be blown away forever! If you have changes you wish to take with you, make sure you stash them first (or commit then cherry pick).

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. However, I'm still left with the initial question - I don't want to push the local changes, just delete them. However, reset to HEAD (or git clean -f) doesn't remove the unpushed changes. Shouldn't it? and if not, how to do that w/o actually pushing them?

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. My confusion was apparently between reset --hard HEAD and reset --hard origin/xyz and assuming that they were synonymous.

Comment: I'm a visual person and I always use `gitk --all` whenever I'm meddling  with this kind of thing. Helps me see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The branch is tracking another branch as being "upstream" of it.  This means that what you have in your branch is really new and if you want to get rid of that message, just use

```
git push
```

While on that branch.

---

If you want to never have that message pop up, then use

```
git config --unset branch.xyz.merge
```